# How can I make rectangle shape in turtle, python?

Tags: python

python how can i make the shapes?
This is what I did

```
import turtle,random,sys

turtle.title("SHOT")
turtle.setup (width=800, height=600)
turtle.bgcolor("light green")
turtle.screensize(10, 400)

class boxes:
     box_A = turtle.getturtle()
     box_B = turtle.getturtle()

     box_A.hideturtle()
     box_B.hideturtle()
     box_A.setposition(-300,0)
     box_A.setposition(300,0)
     box_A.showturtle()
     box_B.showturtle()
```

And my computer draw line... I don't want line... 
so I want to erase the line and 
I want to make a rectangle boxes(two) 
I tried to make rectangle with

```
 box_A.shape("rectangle")
```

Definitely, it wasn't working;;;

guys plz help me

Comment: Why are you making a class there? All those calls in the class body will happen at class definition time and instantiating the class will do nothing.

Comment: thanks I thought the class is set of variable

Comment: You do have the two turtle instances as class attributes, but the stuff where you call methods on them is already executed when the class definition has finished.

Comment: besides the turtle pen had gone left first and then went to right side

Comment: So, how can I make just two boxes on both sides ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom shape by using coordinates. First, do the normal statements.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen() # The Screen is VERY important for this project!
```

Ok! Now to change `t`'s shape, we have to enter a set of coordinates. Here are a few presets you can use I made:

```
Pointer: ((15,0),(0,25),(-15,0),(0,3))
Noel Star: ((0,20),(-5,5),(-20,0),(-5,-5),(0,-20),(5,-5),(20,0),(5,5))
X: ((15,15),(-15,-15),(0,0),(15,-15),(-15,15),(0,0))
Cross: ((-7.5,-15),(7.5,-15),(7.5,-7.5),(15,-7.5),(15,7.5),(7.5,7.5),(7.5,15),(-7.5,15),(-7.5,7.5),(-15,7.5),(-15,-7.5),(-7.5,-7.5))
Right Triangle: ((20,0),(0,-20),(0,0))
Arrow: ((-15,7.5),(-10,0),(-15,-7.5),(5,-7.5),(15,0),(5,7.5))
Parallelogram: ((-30,20),(-40,-20),(30,-20),(40,20)) 
Rhombus: ((0,-20),(-10,0),(0,20),(10,0))
Trapezoid: ((-20,20),(20,20),(30,0),(-30,0))
Pentagon: ((-5,10),(-10,0),(-5,-10),(5,-10),(10,0),(5,10))
Hexagon: ((-10,20),(-20,0),(-10,-20),(10,-20),(20,0),(10,20))
Octagon: ((-10,20),(10,20),(20,10),(20,-10),(10,-20),(-10,-20),(-20,-10),(-20,10))
```

The rectangle's coordinates are: `((-20,10),(20,10),(20,-10),(-20,-10))`. To register this as a custom shape, use the `register_shape()` function. The first argument is what you will name the shape; 'rectangle', in this case. The second argument is the coordinates, so save them as a variable.

```
rectCors = ((-20,10),(20,10),(20,-10),(-20,-10));
s.register_shape('rectangle',rectCors);
```

Ok. Now just tell the turtle that its shape is a rectangle.

```
t.shape('rectangle');
```

Done! In total, thats:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle();
s = turtle.Screen();
rectCors = ((-20,10),(20,10),(20,-10),(-20,-10));
s.register_shape('rectangle',rectCors);
t.shape('rectangle');
```

Note:
There is no way to change the shape from horizontal to vertical, if you were wondering, except `t.setheading(90)` or `t.setheading(-90)`.

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
    object.shape("square")
    object.shapesize(X, Y)
```

this will make a rectangle based on it's pixels
or do this

```
    object.shape("square")
    object.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
```

this will produce a rectangle based on a ratio of 5:1, each unit is a square

Answer (score 0):

Draw four lines:

```
 box_A.setposition(-300,0)
 box_A.setposition(-300,200)
 box_A.setposition(0,200)
 box_A.setposition(0,0)
```

Comment: I think my question is not complete.

Comment: I am trying to make game . work like angry birds, so I want to make two rectangle on both side (300,0),(-300,0) and then create two ball to shot so when one player input angle and velocity the ball would be shot , the player try to destroy the other player's rectangle box

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying too do

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.tracer()

bird = turtle.Turtle()
bird.shape("square")
```

You have to do square, rect isn't a shape in turtle

```
bird.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=10)
```

Then just stretch it too a rectangle by making the width longer than height

```
bird.color("green")
bird.setpos(0, 0)
bird.penup()
```

Penup is for if you're moving it, it won't draw a line behind it

```
bird.speed(0)
```

The speed just makes the animation instant if you do that

```
wn.exitonclick()
```

Hope this helped